# Relation between Login Name and User Name

Tags: sql-server

Just talking about SQL Server auhentication, has a Login Name to be the same from the User Name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the login name and user name do not have to be the same - you can create a different user name in each database, all based off the same server-level login.

```
USE master;
GO 

CREATE LOGIN foo WITH PASSWORD = 'bar', CHECK_POLICY = OFF;
GO

USE tempdb;
GO

CREATE USER blat FROM LOGIN [foo];
GO
```

That said, why would you want to do this? It's completely confusing.

Comment: You are right, it just happened that didn't work immediately.  I was just playing with the SQL Server Management Studio, just for the sake of learning. When i created a new login, i named it with the suffix Login. After, when creating a user in the DB, i gave it name with the suffix User, and chose the previous login.

Comment: @biergarten that shouldn't be necessary. Just like there's no reason to name a table `tblCustomers` or a procedure `sp_something`.

Comment: It depends. I like to have a minimun of readabilty in the scripts, and suffixes/prefixes help

Comment: And you're going to achieve a "minimum of readability", so mission accomplished. :)